# Apache Pig: ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: can't look backwards more than one token in this stream

Tags: apache-pig

I wrote a UDF that returns a string and here is a sample code:

```
split data into purchased IF ((boolean) (myudf(param)), failed OTHERWISE;
```

As an example, here is the example of that my udf returns:

```
split data into purchased IF ((boolean) (retcode == 'SUCCESS')), failed OTHERWISE;
```

Unfortunately. I get the following error:

```
Apache Pig: ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: can't look backwards more than one token in this stream
```

I also tried this:

```
split data into purchased IF ((boolean) '(retcode == 'SUCCESS')'), failed OTHERWISE;
```

I get this error:

```
2015-06-19 10:10:48,330 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 11, column 85>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near '250.00'
```

I also tried this:

```
split data into purchased IF ((boolean) '(retcode == \'SUCCESS\')'), failed OTHERWISE;
```

I don't get any error, but the I don't get the expected result back.
Any help with this would be great.

Comment: what version of pig are you on?

Comment: I am using CDH 5.3.2 and pig version 0.12.0 that is shipped with it.

Answer (score 0):

That error is thrown because ANTLR can't parse correctly that sentence. Pig should give you a different error showing what is the problem, like it generally does, but it seems the parsing rules for the `SPLIT` sentence don't take into account what happens when you try to cast the condition.

The problem here is solved simply by removing that cast to `boolean`:

```
split data into purchased IF (retcode == 'SUCCESS'), failed OTHERWISE;
```

That will work.

Why does the cast make it fail? That I don't know. I guess that casting the output of an expression counts as two different expressions, since it has to resolve the inner expression to apply the cast afterwards, and the syntax rule for the `split` operator does not allow this. 0% sure though.